# After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018

Tags: certificate, javascript, node.js

Certificates are a very complicated issue. After **a lot** of tries and victories to run a open source in Linux called [FreedomGPT](https://github.com/ohmplatform/FreedomGPT), I received this error related to NSS certificate. More details showed in following image:

[image: Error in console]

I can't run as root (`[electron_main_delegate.cc(300)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported`). FreedomGPT shows window but doesn't respond.